# Closure Compiler does not remove dead code from self invoking functions

Tags: typescript, google-closure-compiler, tsickle

I'm writing a TypeScript app which takes two numbers and prints the sum of the numbers to the console.

`calculator2.ts`:

```
export namespace calculator
{
    export function add(a: number, b: number): number
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    export function subtract(a: number, b: number): number
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

`app.ts`:

```
import {calculator} from './calculator2';

var answer = calculator.add(3, 4);
console.log('Answer: ' + answer);
```

I ran tsickle to transpile the TypeScript to JavaScript that the Google Closure Compiler understands. Then I ran the Closure Compiler with the advanced optimization flag to minify my code.

This is the output (pretty-printed):

```
var a;
(function(d) {
  d.add = function(b, c) {
    return b + c;
  };
  d.a = function(b, c) {
    return b - c;
  };
})(a || (a = {}));
var e = a.add(3, 4);
console.log("Answer: " + e);
```

This prints 7, just as expected, but the `calculator.subtract()` (`d.a` in the minified code) is not removed, while I'm not using it.

If I modify the `calculator` file like this:

```
export var calculator: any =
{
    add: function(a: number, b: number): number
    {
        return a + b;
    },

    subtract: function(a: number, b: number): number
    {
        return a - b;
    }
};
```

The Closure Compiler outputs this:

```
console.log("Answer: 7");
```

Is there a way to tell the Closure Compiler that the `subtract` function is not called (at least not from `app.ts`) and that it can be removed?

Another test:

Using 'calculator3.ts'

```
export class calculator
{
    public add(a: number, b: number): number
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public subtract(a: number, b: number): number
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

and 'app.ts'

```
import {calculator} from './calculator3';

var myCalculator = new calculator();
var answer = myCalculator.add(3, 4);
console.log('Answer: ' + answer);
```

generates:

```
var c = (new (function() {
  function a() {
  }
  a.prototype.add = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };
  return a;
}())).add(3, 4);
console.log("Answer: " + c);
```

Which removes the `subtract` function, but is not optimized to `console.log("Answer: 7")` (which is not necessary, but would be great)